# Mark Gitlab CI stage as passed based on condition in job log

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a bash script that is executing a dataflow job like so

/deploy.sh

```
python3 main.py \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--region us-west1 \
--job_name name \
--project project \
--autoscaling_algorithm THROUGHPUT_BASED \
--max_num_workers 10 \
--environment prod \
--staging_location gs staging loc \
--temp_location temp loc \
--setup_file ./setup.py \
--subnetwork subnetwork \
--experiments use_network_tags=internal-ssh-server
```

So I use gitlab ci to run this

./gitlab-ci.yml

```
Deploy Prod:
  stage: Deploy Prod
  environment: production
  script:
    - *setup-project
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip;
    - pip install -r requirements.txt;
    - chmod +x deploy.sh
    - ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```

So now my code runs and logs in the gitlab pipeline AND in the logs viewer in dataflow. What I want to be able to do is that once gitlab sees JOB_STATE_RUNNING, it marks the pipeline as passed and stops outputting logs to gitlab. Maybe there's a way to do this in the bash script? Or can it be done in gitlab ci?

[image]

Comment: how was your *setup-project done, i am struggling to set GCP authentication done

Answer (score 0):

GitLab doesn't have this capability as a feature, so your only is to script the solution.

Something like this should work to monitor the output and exit once that text is encountered.

```
python3 myscript.py > logfile.log &
( tail -f -n0 logfile.log & ) | grep -q "JOB_STATE_RUNNING"
echo "Job is running. We're done here"
exit 0
```

reference: https://superuser.com/a/900134/654263

You'd need to worry about some other things in the script, but that's the basic idea. GitLab unfortunately has no success condition based on trace output.

Comment: hmm, doesn't appear to be working. With this and the other highly rated answer on the comment chain you posted result in the gitlab job just hanging

Comment: Ah, I see. Probably because the `tail -f` keeps piping into grep and the next line won't go until the command finishes (which it wont). Can you try the approach described [here](https://superuser.com/a/449307) instead and see if that works? If it does, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yep, I've unfortunately tried that one as well, and it still hangs until the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Little late, hope this helps someone, The way i solved it was I created two scripts

build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# This helps submit the beam dataflow job using nohup and parse the results for job submission
nohup stdbuf -oL bash ~/submit_beam_job.sh &> ~/output.log &

# Wait for log file to appear before checking on it
sleep 5
# Count to make sure the while loop is not stuck
cnt=1

while ! grep -q "JOB_STATE_RUNNING" ~/output.log; do
echo "Job has not started yet, waiting for it to start"
cnt=$((cnt+1))
if [[ $cnt -gt 5 ]]; then
    echo "Job submission taking too long please check!"
    exit 1
fi
# For other error on the log file, checking the keyword
if grep -q "Errno" ~/output.log || grep -q "Error" ~/output.log; then
    echo "Error submitting Dataflow job, please check!!"
    exit 1
fi
sleep 30
done
```

The submit beam job is like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# This submits individual beam jobs for each topics
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
# Beam pipeline for carlistingprimaryimage table
python3 ~/dataflow.py \
--input_subscription=projects/data-warehouse/subscriptions/cars \
--window_size=2 \
--num_shards=2 \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--temp_location=gs://bucket/beam-python/temp/ \
--staging_location=gs://bucket/beam-python/binaries/ \
--max_num_workers=5 \
--project=data-warehouse \
--region=us-central1 \
--gcs_project=data-warehouse \
--setup_file=~/setup.py
```